# is it possible to use pyexecjs with scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I stumbled upon pyexecjs a while ago, and I was wondering if it could be used with scrapy to crawl JS generated data.
https://github.com/doloopwhile/PyExecJS

I checked the examples of how the library should be used, but I'm not sure how can I integrate it with scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to try Selenium with PhantomJS. Here is an example code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.taobao.com/"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='q']")
bnt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn-search']")
input.send_keys("watch")
bnt.submit()
```

For more information about the API, please refer to [WebDriver API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)
As for how to integrate selenium with scrapy, my advice is embedding it in the parse function of you spider. For example: